# Netty 4 Pipeline for JSON over Websocket

Tags: json, websocket, netty

I want to use Netty as a websocket server. On top I'd like to send JSON between the browser and the server for data interchange.

The websocket part works already fine (I'm using this code: https://github.com/raphaelstary/jsug-netty-example). Now I'd like to integrate a JSON Encoder/Deocoder into the pipeline. I found some code in the Netty Repo I would like to use (still beta, but I wanna try: https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/479b0fe43b6f9a06143cb39f09c51615df90fd1e)

Question: how do I use the Encoder/Decoder in the Pipeline in order to receive and send JSON Objects in my Handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the JSON codec you mentioned, you could just send and receive a `TextWebSocketFrame` which contains the JSON string as its content and feed the JSON string into your favorite JSON library such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)